# Kubectl rollout status , freeze

Tags: kubernetes

I updated the image of the deployment using the command ,

**kubectl set image deployments/deployment_name deployment_name=image** .

I get a response 
**deployment "bumblebee" image updated**.

Then when I describe the deployment it points to the new image , But when I checkout the status using , 
**kubectl rollout status deployment/deployment_name** , 
I get a message : **Waiting for deployment spec update to be observed...** (And it freezes after this)

And no new replica sets are created and when I try to check this out in my dashboard I can see this 
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XuL25.png)

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 0):

The process itself is pretty straight forward, so I have to assume some human error or something was missed here, I would suggest the following debug:

1) start by getting to a place where you have a working deployment, as in reset your environment.
One important consideration would be the repository the image is being pulled form, I know you stated that you're seeing the new image name but is this a public repository that's accessible or is it like an AWS ecr?
Is the rollout working at this point?

2) once you have a working deployment, delete it, and create a new deployment in the exact same way you got the first one to work with the new image - you want to see if it's a problem with the image or something else (for example yml indentation)

3) if you get a new deployment with the new image working, then we can circle back to the original problem which is using the set command, some suggestions would be to maybe use the edit command: `kubectl edit deployment/deployment-name`
maybe use notepad to manually edit the image, maybe there are spaces or some windows linux issue like LF vs CR LF etc.. let me know if that helps.